# Copy a 2D array from Kernel to User

Tags: c, arrays, linux-kernel

I am making a SYSCALL that takes in a user's buffer and a user's 2D array. The SYSCALL will parse through the buffer and I set a 2D array in kernel space to the strings I parsed through in the buffer. I have seen other posts state that the easiest way is to just copy over one buffer that contains all of the parsed information, but I want the array to get copied instead. Here is the general setup of my SYSCALL:

```
SYSCALL(..., char __user **doubleBuf, ...)
int len = 0; //stores the length of kdoubleBuf
char *kdoubleBuf[256]; //create 2D array
```

These are my types. I parse through the buffer and get exactly what I need in kdoubleBuf.

```
for(i = 0; i < 0; i++)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", kdoubleBuf[i]);
}
```

This will print out in dmesg correctly as

```
stringone
stringtwo
etc...
```

This is EXACTLY what I want and I know everything works up to here it is just when I attempt to copy the array to the user's array.

I know I am wrong here because I attempt to copy pointers over from kernel to user space, so when I print out doubleBuf[i] it is just a null pointer.

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    //THIS IS WRONG!
    copy_to_user(doubleBuf[i], kdoubleBuf[i], sizeof(kdoubleBuf[i]));
    //check for errors here
}
```

How can I deep copy over the kdoubleBuf to doubleBuf and avoid a shallow copy?

EDIT: Please note that the user space 2D array is already allocated via:

```
user_array[128][256]; //Or do I need to use malloc()?
```

EDIT 2" SOLVED I dynamically allocated doubleBuf.

Comment: User definition char `user_array[128][256]` is **incompatible** with a way, how you pass it to the syscall: `char __user **doubleBuf`. You may use `char __user (*doubleBuf)[128]` or `char __user doubleBuf[128][256]` as a syscall argument.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up dynamically allocating the doubleBuf instead, but I did not know the kernel would see a difference in how the 2D array was implemented. I assume it is just a compiler thing?

Comment: These are pure "C" language concepts.

Comment: Unfortunately spent to much time with electrical engineering, really should have focused on comp sci :(